# How to solve false positive error 'P/Invoke entry points should exist'?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, winapi

Before asking I've seen the same problem and question [in this C# post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147597/p-invoke-entry-points-should-exist-with-what-should-be-correct-entry-points-st), it tells what is causing the false positive on the code analysis tool, but does not tells how to solve the problem and that is why I'm asking for.

I've these API declarations:

```
    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowLong", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Friend Shared Function GetWindowLong32(
        ByVal hWnd As HandleRef,
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal nIndex As WindowAttributes
    ) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowLongPtr", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Friend Shared Function GetWindowLong64(
        ByVal hWnd As HandleRef,
       <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal nIndex As WindowAttributes
    ) As Long
    End Function
```

When I pass a code-analysis tool, it can't find the entry point of the `GetWindowLongPtr` function.

I've VS2013 Ultimate, I'm compiling for x64 and I've read [this article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182208.aspx).

There is an official way to solve this problem without suppressing the error message in the code-analysis tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This eliminates the CS message/flag, but you'll have to check if it still works as expected (I cant think of a testbed case):

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowLongA", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
Friend Shared Function GetWindowLong64(
    ByVal hWnd As HandleRef,
   <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal nIndex As WindowLongFlags
) As Long
End Function
```